# RKHS of a Polynomial Kernel with negative roots

Tags: reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel), and actually all books and ressources I could find, define a polynomlial kerenel as:

$$
K: x,y \mapsto (x^Ty + c)^2,
$$
where $c\ge 0$. **What happens if $c < 0$?** Take the following kernels for example:

$$
\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}
\begin{cases}
K_+: (x,y)\mapsto (xy + 1)^2 \\
K_-: (x,y)\mapsto (xy - 1)^2
\end{cases}
$$

Both $K_+$ and $K_-$ are positive definite kernel and therefore both have an RKHS. Shouldn't  $K_-$ be included in the polynomial kernel definition?

Another question I have about this example is: although it is quite easy to find $K_+$'s RKHS, **it seems way more difficult to find a closed form expression of $K_-$'s RKHS**.

An idea could be to see $K_-$ as a $90º$ rotation of $K_+$, but I couldn't get from this to a proper expression of the associated Hilbert space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You wrote $K_+$ twice

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thanks! Just edited it.